# Octopus Deploy and Multiple Branches/Release Candidates

Tags: release, release-management, octopus-deploy

We have currently released our code to Production, and as a result have *cut* and branched to ensure we can support our current release, whilst still supporting hot-fixes without breaking the current release from any on-going development.

Here is our current structure:

```
Project-
/Development
/RC1
```

Until recently using Octopus we have had the following process:

```
Dev->Staging/Dev Test->UAT
```

Which works fine as we didn't have an actual release.

My question is how can Octopus support our new way of working?

Do we create a new/clone project in Octopus named RC1 and have CI from our RC1 branch into that? Then add/remove as appropriate as this RC's are no longer required?

Or is there another method that we've clearly missed out on?

Answer (score 5):

It seems that most organisations that are striving for continuous *something* end up with a CI server and continuous deployment up to some manual sign off environment and then require continuous delivery to production. This generally leads to a branching strategy in order to isolate the release candidate to allow hot fixing.

I think a question like this raises more points for discussion, before trying to provide a one size fits all answer IMHO.

The kind of things that spring to mind are:

1. Do you have "source code" dependencies or binary ones for any shared components.
2. What level of integration / automated regression testing do you have.
3. Is your deployment orchestrated by TFS, or driven by a user in Octopus.
4. Is there a database as part of the application that needs consideration.
5. How is your application version numbering controlled.
6. What is your release cycle.

In the past where I've encountered this scenario, I would look towards a code promotion branching strategy which provides you with one branch to maintain in production - This has worked well where continuous deployment to production is not an option. You can find more branching strategies discussed on the [ALM Rangers page on CodePlex](https://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/releases)

Developers / Testers can continually push code / features / bug fixes through staging / uat. At the point of release the Dev branch is merged to Release branch, which causes a release build and creates a nuget package. This should still be released to Octopus in exactly the same way, only it's a brand new release and not a promotion of a previous release. This would need to ensure that there is no clash on version numbering and so a strategy might be to have a difference in the major number - This would depend on your current setup. This does however, take an opinionated view that the deployment is orchestrated by the build server rather than Octopus Deploy. Primarily TeamCity / TFS calls out to the Ocotpus API, rather than a user choosing the build number in Octopus (**we have been known to make mistakes**)

```
ocoto.exe create-release --version GENERATED_BY_BUILD_SERVER
```

To me, the biggest question I ask clients is "What's the constraint that means you can't continuously deploy to production". Address that constraint (see theory of constraints) and you remove the need to work round an issue that needn't be there in the first place (not always that straight forward I know)

I would strongly advise that you don't clone projects in Octopus for different environments as it's counter intuitive. At the end of the day you're just telling Octopus to go and get this nuget package version for this app, and deploy it to this environment please. If you want to get the package from a different NuGet feed for release, then you could always make use of the custom binding on the NuGet field in Octopus and drive that by a scoped variable depending on the environment you're deploying to.

**Step 1 - Setup two feeds**

[image: Setup Two Feeds]

**Step 2 - Scope some variables for those feeds**

[image: Scope Some Variables]

**Step 3 - Consume the feed using a custom expression**

[image: Use a custom expression for the feed]

I hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

This is unfortunately something Octopus doesn't directly have - *true* support for branching (yet). It's on their [roadmap](http://octopusdeploy.com/roadmap) for 3.1 under [better branching support](https://octopusdeploy.uservoice.com/forums/170787-general/suggestions/3480536-branch-support-for-deploying-older-app-versions). They have been [talking about this problem](http://octopusdeploy.com/blog/rfc-branching) for some time now.

One idea that you mentioned would be to clone your project for each branch. You can do this under the "Settings" tab (on the right-hand side) in your project that you want to clone. This will allow you to duplicate your project and simply rename it to one of your branches - so one PreRelease or Release Candidate project and other is your mainline Dev (I would keep the same name of the project). I'm assuming you have everything in the same project group.

Alternatively you could just change your NuSpec files in your projects in different branches so that you could clearly see what's being deployed at the overview project page or on the dashboard. So for your RC branch, you could just add the suffix -release within the NuSpec in your RC branch which is legal ([rules on Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org) talk about prereleases at rule #9). This way, you can use the same project but have different packages to deploy. If your targeted servers are the same, then this may be the "lighter" or simpler approach compared to cloning.

Comment: These are called Channels in the latest version of Octopus Deploy (3.2.6)

Answer (score 0):

I blogged about how we do this here:
http://www.alexjamesbrown.com/blog/development/working-branch-deployments-tfs-octopus/

It's a bit of a hack, but in summary:

- Create branch in TFS Create branch specific build definition
- Create branch specific drop location for Octopack
- Create branch specific Octopus Deployment Project (by cloning your ‘main’ deployment
- Edit the newly cloned deployment, re-point the nuget feed location to your
  branch specific output location, created in step 3